# How to convert java jdbc code to Maximo code

Tags: java, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I have a requirement with existing java Data access code  with Oracle database convert to Maximo data access code.

Current code is calling oracle stored procedure and return the results after googled found that we can use import Maximo lib and call the Maximo objects database. Its my thought.Not sure it is correct.

I am new to Maximo. Can any one help me how to go further.

java jdbc code.

cstmt = dbconn.prepareCall(ISSVRFY);

```
            cstmt.setString(1,req);
            cstmt.setString(2,errorMsg);
            cstmt.setInt(3, statusCode);

            //Set all the out parameters
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

Any Maximo reference code or link  is helpful.

Comment: Is this code running inside the Maximo ear or external to it? Is the logic in the Maximo code replacing that of the stored procedure, or simply calling it still (like the JDBC code)?

Comment: The code is running external.Plan to replace Jdbc code with Maximo code because the database used here is Maximo DB

Comment: Maximo doesn't have its own database engine; it leverages Oracle, MS SQL Server or DB2, depending on what you install. So I don't understand the statement "the database used here is Maximo DB". The "Maximo Business Objects" are just Java code to wrap the normal database interaction and include Maximo's data processing logic. Also to clarify, your response implies (but does not actually answer) that you want the Maximo code to simply call the stored procedure, not replace the stored procedure itself.

Comment: Maximo's business objects don't/can't call stored procedures. If you want to call a stored procedure like you demonstrate, you still have to do what you demonstrated. If you want to replace the stored procedure with Java code using as many MBOs as you can, then that's another story...